# What happens with a CD-KEY of a steam game if I add the same game through a pack?

Tags: steam

I have a game added to my steam library a long time ago (I redeemed it with a physical retail CD-key, let's call "**XXXX**") and then I would know what happens with this retail cd-key if I buy a steam key ("**YYYY**") of a pack collection of various games that includes this same game that I had redeem with a retail CD-Key, so then after activating this pack will I have the same retail CD-Key still for this specific game (the "**XXXX**"), or it will be changed for other different key ("**ZZZZ**")?

Comment: Are you buying the pack through Steam itself or a service such as Humble Bundle? Or is it a physical CD for a bundle?

Comment: A steam key of a pack bought of others store differents of steam (for example humble, amazon, gmg), I know that the games that I owned in my library won't be added/duplicated nor give me extra copies, but I have the doubt of if the retail cd-keys of these owned games will change for new keys or remain with the same original retail cd-key.

Comment: And you're asking whether or not you'll be given the exact same key you used for a game, correct?

Comment: As far as I know: once redeemed: forever locked to that account. Retail or not doesn't matter. You can't sell that retail game anyway. because that key is locked to your account.

Answer (score 3):

As you know, CD keys can only be used once (or deactivated before it is used, from the developer's side). *Once used, they'll go into a list of used keys, where it'll be eventually (after a very long time^) be reused.*

If you apply a new CD key containing a subset of games and you own copies of one (or more) of the games you have already owned is in that bundle, **you do not get a second copy, or a new CD key in replacement to the old one.**
All you get is the remaining games (and DLC's) in the bundle that you do not already own that the key grants.

However, [there are exceptions to the rule](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4502-TPJL-2656&l=english) but only apply to games purchased from the Steam Store, and are granted as a Steam Gift (item).

^Open to speculation

Comment: "where it'll be eventually (after a very long time^) be reused." Source?

Comment: "Open to speculation"